# Questions with multiple language tags: what's the limit?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I have searched for [questions like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=are+questions+with+no+specific+language+on+topic) before asking but found none. If a user would like to solve an issue that can be solved in any language, is it in order for users to answer such questions.

For more context:

In most cases, these questions have no attempt but simply dump data and add any language tag say [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). While these questions can and in my opinion should be closed, they are often answered so fast because they have way more traffic hence making it hard to close them.

How different are these questions from "give me the codes" kind of questions?
Sorry if this question already exists.

Comment: Maybe those questions should be retagged to [tag:language-agnostic]

Comment: Thanks, first time seeing this tag. The issue here is that these questions are really not about say the basics of CS as a field in general but rather on  a specific problem. User will for instance want to read a csv file, they simply dump their data, no effort, just multiple tags and often: **I need this to be done in r, python or excel**.

Comment: How about down vote the question and all the answers, post a cv-pls in SOCVR and move on.

Comment: I don't really downvote answers but always vote to close. Questions almost never get closed. What is a cv-pls?

Comment: It's how you request getting help closing an off topic question in the Stack Overflow Close Vote chat Room.

Comment: See the FAQ topic of SOCVR about the cv-pls usage: https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests

Comment: I usually just vote "too broad". If the question shows at least a glint of promise I might comment to urge the asker to narrow it down or even edit out the irrelevant tags, as long as it's clear they are irrelevant (OP shows JS code but has tags for `javascript`, `python`, `java`, for example). But some questions are really "I want to do X, don't care which language it is in" which is still too broad. It also fully warrants a downvote since there is no research effort - the asker couldn't even determine which language to use.

Comment: Down voting answers is important. If you manage to close such a question you really want to have it gone from the site. That can happen in  9 days if it gets closed and none of the answers have a score >0. As it is more likely to pick up a stray up vote the it is to get a down vote, one up vote accident will prevent deletion. When I assume most answerers of these questions are in there for the rep, they are more likely to remove their post and pick better questions next time. If done correctly you'll regain any reputation you lost due to the down vote, if the post gets removed.

Comment: related: roomba: https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: Thanks all. I guess I should utilise this "hidden feature" more.